# Conditional Docker Volumes Created Even When ARG is Empty

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, arguments, volume

I'm encountering an issue with my Docker project where it seems that Docker volumes are being created even when the `SRC_VOLUME` argument in my Dockerfile is empty. Here's my simplified Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile

# This works as expected
ARG SRC_VOLUME=./src

# However, when the argument is empty, it still creates volumes in ./src
ARG SRC_VOLUME=
```

And here's my simplified Docker Compose file:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3.8"

services:
  poetry-test:
    build:
      context: .  # Build context is the current directory.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # Use specified Dockerfile for building.
    volumes:
      - ${SRC_VOLUME:-/dev/null}:${VARIABLE:-/code}
```

- `${SRC_VOLUME:-/dev/null}:${VARIABLE:-/code}`: This code creates a volume mapping where it uses the values of `SRC_VOLUME` and `VARIABLE` environment variables if defined, and defaults to `/dev/null` for the source and `/code` for the target if these variables are not set.

In the Dockerfile, I have two versions of the `ARG SRC_VOLUME` line—one with a default value of `./src` and another where the argument is left empty. My expectation was that Docker would only create volumes if the `SRC_VOLUME` argument is set to a non-empty string. However, in both cases, Docker seems to create volumes in the `./src` directory.

Is there a way to conditionally create Docker volumes based on whether the `SRC_VOLUME` argument is set to a non-empty value or not?

Comment: Dockerfile `ARG` isn't considered at all in Compose `volumes:`; conversely, you don't need to declare anything in your Dockerfile to allow Compose `volumes:`.  It looks like you might be trying to overwrite your application's code with a volume mount, which can lead to inconsistent behavior, and in that case I'd recommend deleting this `volumes:` block entirely.  The linked question describes the setup you're trying to run in more detail; broadly, conditional `volumes:` aren't possible.